# Creating instances of classes in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Without using CodeIgniter I would normally just do;

```
require_once("object");

test = new object();
```

How would I go about doing this in CodeIgniter?

Edit: for example this class could be a video game object. It might be holding a number of variables, for example title, age,description etc. There would also be variable get/set methods for the above variables.

For example, I might use this class to help contain the information created by a database search.

Comment: Seems like something the documentation would cover.

Comment: It depends on what the class is. A model is loaded like $this->load->model('model_name'); a library is similarly $this->load->library('library_name') and so on. The docs are pretty clear on this so maybe you should explain what you're hoping to do and we can give you direction based on that. --- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/libraries.html for example

Comment: Edited the op to contain more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter uses the Singleton design pattern and most of your classes are loaded using the loader class (as needed, in a constructor, or in the autoload config file) and are then available via the Codeigniter Super Object `$this->my_model`. As Kai Qing noted, using a Model would typically entail:

```
// In the constructor, controller method, or autoload
$this->load->model('my_model');

// Then to use a method simply
$this->my_model->my_method();
```

In Codeigniter classes are more like utility classes to group like functionality. However, you can always use native PHP in Codeigniter to require a class and then instantiate your own objects.

Comment: After reading the doc of models I think its what I need but the fact it's able to access a DB, while also being a container for objects of the DB just completely hurts my head. 

I'm used to having an object class and then having a separate class which has the DB methods which then use the object class, if that makes any sense at all.